# how to solve the chown permission issue of postgresql docker container when mount the nfs volume?

Tags: docker, nfs

I am using docker on Mac and trying to get a persistent container of postgresql database using nfs volume.

I put one line `/Users/me/db -alldirs *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)` in `/etc/exports` and restart nfsd. I think(correct me if I am wrong) the key point is no_root_squash which will allow the client root user to be still root user.Then in my docker-compose.yml, I declare the nfsmount point as  the follwing:

```
version: '2'
volumes:
  nfsmountdbdata:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: nfs
      o: addr=host.docker.internal,rw,nolock,hard,nointr,nfsvers=3
      device: ":/Users/me/db/data"
  nfsmountdbinit:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: nfs
      o: addr=host.docker.internal,rw,nolock,hard,nointr,nfsvers=3
      device: ":/Users/me/db/initdb"
services:

  ## POSTGRES DATABASE
  db:
    image: postgres:9.6
    privileged: true
    volumes:
      #- ./services/db/initdb:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      #- ./services/db/app:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - nfsmountdbinit:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - nfsmountdbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

But when the container db starts, it complains a lot about `chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/postgresql/data/base/**/**': Operation not permitted`. It makes me feel very confused as I have done something(no_root_squash configuration in nfs) to fix it. But it just does not work. What's wrong with my understanding here? I am using Mac Mojave and Docker desktop for Mac 2.0.0.0 stabel.

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a new image to change the user, you can just run the postgres image as a different user instead:

```
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6
    environment:
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    user: "${UID:?You must do 'export UID' to launch}:${GID:?You must do 'export GID' to launch}"
    volumes:
      - nfsmountdbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I solved this...

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM postgres:9.6
ARG GNAME='groupname'
ARG GID='groupid'
ARG USERID=999

# fix permissions so it can persist data on the host nfs file system
RUN groupadd -g $GID $GNAME \
 && usermod -g $GNAME postgres \
 && usermod -u $USERID postgres

# go get the entrypoint script from their git hub link and details to follow
COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["postgres"]
```

Get the Postgres Entrypoint scrip [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker-library/postgres/a9610d18de51c189c9d4b0197c408e2e3bfb7917/9.6/docker-entrypoint.sh)

Make edits to it commenting out lines 34, 35, 36 52, 53, 54. Basically where it tries to `chmod` and `chown` the NFS folders.

```
...
if [ "$1" = 'postgres' ] && [ "$(id -u)" = '0' ]; then
    #mkdir -p "$PGDATA"
    #chown -R postgres "$PGDATA"
    #chmod 700 "$PGDATA"
...
if [ "$1" = 'postgres' ]; then
    #mkdir -p "$PGDATA"
    #chown -R "$(id -u)" "$PGDATA" 2>/dev/null || :
    #chmod 700 "$PGDATA" 2>/dev/null || :
...
```

Now build the image...

```
docker build -t postgres9.6:nfs --build-arg GID=<NFS GROUP ID> ==build-arg GNAME=<NFS GROUP NAME> --build-arg USERID=<NFS USER ID> .
```

What I mean by NFS GROUP ID, USER ID, and GROUP NAME is the user/group that has read/write access to the NFS folders.

Now you should have a Postgres Docker image that is capable of using NFS Host Volumes to store the database data.

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Something that worked easiest for me was to add a Dockerfile that did the following:

```
FROM postgres:11.2
ENV TZ=America/Los_Angeles

# Make us the same gid/id as the nfs mount.
RUN sed -i 's/:999:/:5081:/g' /etc/group
RUN sed -i 's/:999:999:/:5081:5081:/g' /etc/passwd


CMD [ "postgres", "-c", "max_connections=10000"]
```